# Zend Framework Multidimensional Form Array

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I need to create a multidimensional array form using zend framework. When I post the form I should be able to get the following result as post.

```
Array
(
    [Address] => Array
        (
            [customer] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Customer Name
                )

            [guest] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Guest Name
                )

        )

)
```

For some reason I am not able to get the above result. So far the result I get is this.

```
Array
(
     [customer_name] => Customer Name
     [guest_name] => Guest Name
)
```

So my question is does Zend_Form support multidimensional form array? If yes how?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can perform operation on your current array to get desire one. Or else have look at [zend subform](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.subforms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issu isn't about ZF, but about `<form>` system.
To retrieve a multidimensional form array, you have to provide good **name** attributes.

In ZF, to manipulate the name, you can use :

`$form->myelement->setAttrib('name', 'myname');` or
`$form->myelement->setName('myname');`

And to do what you expect, you have to use naming form like :

```
$form->element1->setName('[address][customer][name]');
$form->element2->setName('[address][guest][name]');
```

With this naming, you'll be able to retrieve your POST data in a multidimensional array.

Using subforms, you only can manipulate first dimension. So elements would have a naming form like :

```
$subform1->setName('customer');
$subform1->element1->setName('[address][name]');
[...]//do it for each element

$subform2->setName('guest');
$subform2->element1->setName('[address][name]');
[...]//do it for each element
```

Comment: This is a nice work around but is there a way using Zend Subforms? I tried zend subforms but can only go to one array level...

Answer (score 0):

The setName() method of Zend_Form_Element's is filtered and doesn't allow [ and ].

The setBelongsTo() method  is just made for that. But i'm not shure that the setName() and setBelongsTo() couple can handle more than one dimension.